# Why spread operator turn my array into numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, operators, arr, spread

i have

`a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`

How come when i write

`console.log(...a.shift())`
it gives me `1 2 3`
but not `1,2,3` nor `[1, 2, 3]`
can anyone explain me the mechanism behind this?

Comment: You're calling `console.log(...[1,2,3])` which is the same as calling `console.log(1,2,3)`

Comment: right but why does it turn an array into numbers? just confusing for me to have a method that is similar to ```console.log([1,2,3].join(" ")) ``` 
i know it would turn it into string if i use ```.join``` so thats why im just curious about the mechanism underneath the spread operator

Comment: Please explain why you were expecting `1,2,3` or `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: The spread syntax just causes `console.log` to receive multiple arguments, one for each element of the array (doesn't matter whether they're numbers or not). It's `console.log`'s choice to display them with whitespace in between, it could do anything else.

Answer (score 2):

`a.shift()` returns the first element of the array, which is `[1, 2, 3]`. So your code is equivalent to:

```
console.log(...[1, 2, 3])
```

The spread syntax causes each element of the array to become a separate argument, so this is equivalent to

```
console.log(1, 2, 3)
```

which prints each number separately on the console.

To get `[1, 2, 3]` you shouldn't use `...`, just write

```
console.log(a.shift())
```

To get `1,2,3` use

```
console.log(a.shift().join(','))
```

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(...a.shift())`

is run in given order:

1. `a.shift()` returns `[1, 2, 3]`  => `console.log(...[1, 2, 3])`
2. `...[1, 2, 3]` is evaluated into `1 2 3` and passed to console.log as 3 different arguments => `console.log(1, 2, 3)`

Which has out of `1 2 3`

Comment: "*`...[1, 2, 3]` is evaluated into `1 2 3`*" - it's unclear what you mean by `1 2 3`. Is that supposed to represent a string? Something else?

Comment: not a string. its evaluated into three integer values (so to say)

Comment: Well, so to say, no. The `...` is not an operator, it doesn't evaluate to anything at all - it's simply part of the function call syntax.